# Style new Chrome's alert window

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

Is it possible to style the new Chrome `alert` boxes, added in version 29?

Run this javaScript in Chrome's console:

```
alert("This is new")
```

[image]

I ask this because the new window actually looks more like a dialog.

It also displays a tooltip with the coordinates while being dragged.

[image: http://i.snag.gy/xLIu0.jpg]

Comment: Style what? Since when can you style anything in a dialog box except maybe include an icon?

Comment: Probably not, since if you use a special command (or some new alert parameter) to style only Chrome dialogs, it will not be a standard anymore. Since the "fight" in Web is to stardardize client technologies, I don't think that this will ever exist, or we will have scrollbar css styles like old IE versions.

Comment: The button, colors, shape, dimension, padding, anything?

Comment: no you cannot style browser alert boxes, you can however create your own

Comment: So, apparently there's no styling yet.

Comment: The new alert dialog is invisible. I have no idea of what chromium devs (?) where thinking.

Comment: It's not invisible, it's just hard to notice :D

Comment: I don't see the tooltip with coordinates. I think maybe this is particular to your setup, or there is a developer tool switched on? "I ask this because the new window actually looks more like a dialog." - The alert() box is a dialog box - always has been.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, you cannot style dialog boxes (including the newly designed one). Use a JS/HTML modal if you need to style a popup instead.

Comment: I thought this was not dialog box, as it doesn't look like a new browser window.

Comment: The Chromium team may have not used an actual OS level window to create the dialog, but as far as we're concerned it's a dialog that we have no access to.

Comment: Matt, consider posting the above statement as an answer :)

Comment: @ryan No. Matt answered my question :)

Comment: @Cristy ok, you might want to update your question to ask how chromium draws its dialog as opposed to can it be styled.

Comment: The question is pretty clear, it asks about **Chrome**'s dialog, not how to style any alert dialog on any browser.

Comment: Unless you are willing to have users to download an extension there is nothing you can do. I prefer letting the browser handle it since it works a lot better with mobile devices. Custom dialog boxes sometimes can issues on smaller screens. Hopefully the chrome team will at least let you change the position in a future update.